# Have superclass methods call class in correct namespace

Tags: ruby

I have some namespaces that contain duck-type classes, and they all inherit from `Base` namespace, like below:

```
module Base
  class Client
    def self.greet
      puts Wrapper
    end

    def do_stuff
      puts Wrapper
    end
  end

  class Wrapper
  end
end

module Website
  class Client < Base::Client
  end

  class Wrapper < Base::Wrapper
  end
end

Website::Client.greet
Website::Client.new.do_stuff
```

---output---

Base::Wrapper

Base::Wrapper

I would like the above code to print (and reference) Website::Wrapper instead, is there a way to accomplish this by changing my inheritance structure?

Comment: It is not clear in what namespaces you have `Wrapper`. Write them all.

Comment: Sorry, I've edited the code sample to be more complete

Comment: You should also get rid of the following line as it is clearly not what you are doing: `... if I attempt to call another class such as Wrapper.`  This is what you are doing: `Website::Client.greet
Website::Client.new.do_stuff`...so where in Website::Client are you "calling Wrapper"?

Answer (score 0):

If a constant named `Wrapper` is in the top-level namespace you can write `::Wrapper` to refer to it, but usually just writing `Wrapper` is sufficient.

Answer (score 0):

> In Website::Client, if I attempt to call another class such as
>   Wrapper, it will call Base::Wrapper...

I'm not seeing that:

```
module Base

  class Client
  end

  class Wrapper
  end

end

module Website

  class Wrapper < Base::Wrapper
  end

  class Client < Base::Client
    p Wrapper     #=>Website::Wrapper

    def self.greet  #Create class method
      p Wrapper   #=>Website::Wrapper
    end

    def do_stuff
      p Wrapper   #=>Website::Wrapper
    end

  end
end

Website::Client.greet
Website::Client.new.do_stuff

--output:--
Website::Wrapper
Website::Wrapper
Website::Wrapper
```

Can you modify that example to show the problem you are having?

**Response to modified question:**

> Is this just bad practice?

Wouldn't it be surprising to call Base::Client.greet and get Website::Wrapper?

> Is there an easy way to have methods called in the subclass default to
>   that class' namespace?

What do you mean by that?  There is no class method named greet defined in Website::Client's singleton class.  If you want to override Base::Client.greet you can do that.

Also, you are writing Website::Client when you call Website::Client.greet, so you already know from which class the method call originates...but inside Base::Client.greet, you can add the line `puts self`, and that will identify the object that called the method, which is the class Website::Client.

Comment: This is a much clearer layout to my issue, I've copied this layout and posted a much clearer description above, thanks!

Comment: It would be surprising to receive Website::Wrapper in that case, but thats what I'm trying to avoid. I'm basically trying to avoid overwriting methods that have the exact same logic (include namespaced class names). I think i might just get around this by defining a namespaces constant.